# Python 2.7: Trouble Encoding to UTF-8

Tags: python, encoding, utf

I have a dataframe that has a column, `_text`, containing the text of an article.  I'm trying to get the length of the article for each row in my dataframe.  Here's my attempt:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
result_df['_text'] = [BeautifulSoup(text, "lxml").get_text() for text in result_df['_text']]

text_word_length = [len(str(x).split(" ")) for x in result_df['_text']]
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-f6c8ab83a46f> in <module>()
----> 1 text_word_length = [len(str(x).split(" ")) for x in result_df['_text']]

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 231: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Seems like I should be specifying "utf-8" somewhere, I'm just not sure where...

Thanks!

Comment: Try to use `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the beginning of the script? I don't know if it works.

Comment: Please post the fulll traceback of the error your getting in your question.

Comment: @mpf82 Updated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that you use a Python 2 version, and that your input text contains non ASCII characters. The problem arises at `str(x)` which by default when x is a unicode string ends in `x.encode('ascii')`

You have 2 ways to solve this problem:

1. correctly encode the  unicode string in utf-8:

   ```
   text_word_length = [len(x.encode('utf-8').split(" ")) for x in result_df['_text']]
   ```
2. split the string as unicode:

   ```
   text_word_length = [len(x.split(u" ")) for x in result_df['_text']]
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Acording to the official python documentation:
[Python Official Site](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)

To define a source code encoding, a magic comment must be placed into the source files either as first or second line in the file, such as:

```
# coding=<encoding name>
```

or (using formats recognized by popular editors):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: <encoding name> -*-
```

or:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# vim: set fileencoding=<encoding name> :
```

Comment: Unfortunately running that in a Jupyter Notebook doesn't resolve my issue

Comment: This is a nice try but a bad answer. The magic comment is only used to allow non ascii characters in unicode litterals. It does not set the default charset which is normally ascii in Python2 and utf8 in Python3.